# My first React custom hook

Tags: beginner, react.js

I need to change the page title based on the current state of my store. Right now I came up with

```
const useTitle = () => {
  const { foo, bar } = useSelector(selectFoorBar);
  const baz = useSelector(selectBaz);

  const fooBarDisplayString = format(foo, bar);
  const barDisplayString = (bar ?? 0).toFixed(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `${fooBarString} | ${bazDisplayString}`;
  }, [fooBarDisplayString, bazDisplayString]);
};

export default useTitle;
```

Is the name `useTitle` appropriate? It's technically a hook, because it's using other hooks, so it must start with `use` keyword. That feels weird to somebody coming outside of the React world like me. Furthermore, it doesn't return any title, so it's more of a `keepTitleUpToDate()`, which should become `useKeepTitleUpToDate()` which is even weirder. How would you name it?

Is it appropriate to keep this functionality in a hook like I did or is there some other convention in React for stuff that depends on hooks?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any issue with the code.

> It's technically a hook, because it's using other hooks, so it must
> start with use keyword. That feels weird to somebody coming outside of
> the React world like me. Furthermore, it doesn't return any title...

The `use` prefix is just a React hook naming convention, and React hooks aren't required to return anything.

> How would you name it?

If you are merely asking about what to name it, well, this is rather opinionated, but I suggest:

```
useDocumentTitleUpdater
```

Alone the functionality is to update the document title, something like `updateDocumentTitle` or `documentTitleUpdater`. The former, to me, implies you are handing the function the value you want it to update something to, while the latter is more of a delegation, telling the function to update the title. Since this is a React hook and there's a hook naming convention, `useDocumentTitleUpdater` explains the purpose of the hook. It could probably be shortened to `useDocTitleUpdater` if the previous was too verbose for your taste.

> Is it appropriate to keep this functionality in a hook like I did or
> is there some other convention in React for stuff that depends on
> hooks?

This doesn't appear to be an inappropriate use of a React hook. The alternative would be a utility function that consumes the various arguments from redux, runs the two middle lines to compute the strings, and updates the title. This function would be called from a `useEffect` hook with the redux state values as dependencies instead.

Your hook has instead encapsulated this into a single line any functional component can use and they won't be responsible for getting the dependencies correct.